# What is a good way to do a conditional in a link_to for the path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

Ok so i have this link_to

```
%li= link_to 'My Application', new_applications_path
```

but i want to do a conditonal on the path like

```
%li= link_to 'My Application', somecondition ? my_application : new_applications_path
```

can you do a trinary operator in a link_to

Answer (score 2):

Did you try it?

The answer is yes. `link_to` is just a Ruby method and you can use any Ruby expression, including a *ternary* expression, for its parameters. It may be useful to surround the conditional with parentheses to avoid ambiguity, e.g.

```
%li= link_to 'Foo', ( bar ? baz : qux )
```

Comment: And call it from a helper method.